# How to train model on small data (100 labelised data)?

Tags: data-annotations, training-data, text-classification

My company want to offer a new service of data analysis. They want to automatically categorize interview data in different classes (more than 5). But At the moment, only 100 are fully categorized. we will have 1000 others in three months and, 10000 in 12 months so in march 2024. My question is how to work with 100 labelled data, and what can be done until july to at least propose something to manager ? I wanted to amplified the data and start training a pretrained model is it the best way and add the other data which are annotated to improve the model etc... the model need to be implemented in a platform. We just have two people who are fully capable of labelling the data sop they cannot really do a lot in a short time, and they have others obligations.

Some examples of categories (non-exhaustive list):

**Work content
Workload
Organisation
Company life
salary**

Each categories is associated with a list of lexical words.  For example,

**workload**  : Load;Overload;Burn-out;Bore-out;Solicitation;Commitment;Disconnection

***Example of interview 1 :***

Comments of the manager :

•   Tu as dépassé les objectifs fixés et je t’en félicite. En travaillant encore davantage sur l’organisation de tes journées, tu pourras faire encore mieux et devenir un expert dans ton domaine ! »

•    « Lors des rendez-vous avec les prospects, tu devrais passer davantage de temps sur la phase de découverte. Grâce à cela, tu comprendras mieux leur besoin et tu seras sûr que tu as répondu à toutes leurs interrogations. »

Comment: What will you use to differentiate the 5 classes? Need to provide a detailed, but anonymized, example.

Comment: @SolarMike hello I add other information as you wanted ?

Comment: I did something like this with excel and macros... Takes a lot of processing power.